# How to connect the boxes that are in parallell on the left side of the system

Tags: floats

I want to connect the boxes on the left side of the system, that is demarcated by a line dividing it into the CPU side and RF-chain part. Also i would like to reduce the two outermost connecting lines between the (HT)^+ and T box in order to show that the data is compressed over the system. To be clear i want to connect the two (HT)^+ boxes into one big box and the same with the 2 xhat boxes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} % Create graphics in Latex
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=5mm}]

  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (0,0) (x) {$\hat{x}$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (1.5,0) (ht) {$(HT)^+$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (5.5,0) (t) {$T$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (6.5,0) (y) {$Y$};
  \node[block, font=\bfseries] at (8,0) (adc) {ADC};
  \foreach \y in {-0.25, -0.75, 0.25, 0.75}{
    \draw [black, -] ([yshift=\y cm]x.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially x)] in {ht,t,y,adc}
        \draw [black, -] ([yshift=\y cm]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
  }

  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=0.75cm]adc.east)--++(0:.5cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=0.25cm]adc.east)--++(0:1.25cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=-0.25cm]adc.east)--++(0:2cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=-0.75cm]adc.east)--++(0:2.75cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[densely dotted] (3.75,2) -- (3.75,-7);
  \node[draw] at (2,2) {CPU};
  \node[draw] at (6,2) {RF-chain};

  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (0,-5) (x) {$\hat{x}$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (1.5,-5) (ht) {$(HT)^+$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (5.5,-5) (t) {$T$};
  \node[block, font=\boldmath] at (6.5,-5) (y) {$Y$};
  \node[block, font=\bfseries] at (8,-5) (adc) {ADC};
  \foreach \y in {-0.25, -0.75, 0.25, 0.75}{
    \draw [black, -] ([yshift=\y cm]x.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially x)] in {ht,t,y,adc}
        \draw [black, -] ([yshift=\y cm]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
  }

  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=0.75cm]adc.east)--++(0:.5cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=0.25cm]adc.east)--++(0:1.25cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=-0.25cm]adc.east)--++(0:2cm) node[antenna] {};
  \draw[black, -] ([yshift=-0.75cm]adc.east)--++(0:2.75cm) node[antenna] {};
  \node[draw] at (2,2) {CPU};
  \node[draw] at (6,2) {RF-chain};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One sketch what you like to change in temporary code will myke your question far more clear ... If I correct understand, you like to have one shape for $\hat{x}$ and one for $(HT)^+$ with 8 input and output lines?

Comment: Yes that is what I want. My code already shows almost what i want, the only exception is that the two boxes on the left side are not connected with 8 inputs and outputs.

Comment: But i already told you that I want to take away two of the lines between T and (TH)^+ so it is going to be 4 inputs and 8 putputs for the (TH)^+ box. But for the xhat box it is going to be 8 input and 8 output

Comment: meanwhile I suggest possible solution, but in it I still have 8 lines on the CPU side. Please clarify, hof many they are, where they are, that I will be able to correct my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit (2):**
Regarding received comments I now imagine three possible solution of grouping of lines and numbers of antennas:

- 8 input lines, 4 lines between blocks `x` and `HT`, and  other blocks have only two lines and two antennas
- 2 x 4 input lines, 2 x 2 lines between `x` and `HT`, and other blocks have only two lines and two antennas
- 8 input lines, 4 lines between blocks `x` and `HT`, and  other blocks have only two lines and four antennas

Both possibilities are shown below. Still is not clear to me, if to each ADC block are connected two or four antennas. Temporary is assumed, that are only two, however added is also solution for four-

The code is further make shorter, added is tikz library `chains`, all absolute coordinates are removed, so distances between nodes are controlled by `node distance`. Drawing of all lines are merged in heavy nested `foreach` loops

Version 1:

[image]

Version 2:

[image]

Version 3:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,positioning}

    \begin{document}
% version 1
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 16mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
 block/.style = {draw, minimum height=20mm, minimum width=5mm,
                 font=\boldmath,on chain}]
% upper blocks
\node (x1)    [block,draw=none]             {};
\node (ht1)   [block,draw=none]             {\hphantom{$\boldmath(HT)^+$}};
\node (t1)    [block,right=22mm of ht1]     {$T$};
\node (y1)    [block]                       {$Y$};
\node (adc1)  [block]                       {ADC};
% lower blocks
\node (x2)    [block,draw=none,below=of x1] {};
\node (ht2)   [block,draw=none]             {\hphantom{$\boldmath(HT)^+$}};
\node (t2)    [block,right=22mm of ht2]     {$T$};
\node (y2)    [block]                       {$Y$};
\node (adc2)  [block]                       {ADC};
% common input nodes
\node (in1)   [draw,inner sep=0pt, fit= (x1)  (x2), label=center:$\boldmath\hat{x}$] {};
\node (in2)   [draw,inner sep=0pt, fit=(ht1)  (ht2),label=center:$\boldmath(HT)^+$] {};
% top blocks
    \node (cpu) [above=5mm of in2]     {CPU};
    \node (rf)  [above=5mm of y1]      {RF-chain};
\draw[densely dotted] ([xshift=11mm] cpu.north -| in2.east) coordinate (in3)
                    -- (in3 |- in2.south);
% lines between blocks
    \foreach \y in {-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75}
{
% 8 input lines
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm +1 cm] in1.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm -1 cm] in1.west)--++(180:1cm);
% 4 lines between x and HT
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm] in2.west) -- ([yshift=\y cm] in1.east |- in2.west);
}
% 2 lines between other blocks
    \foreach \j in {1, 2}
{
        \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25}
    {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially ht\j)] in {t\j,y\j,adc\j}
    \draw ([yshift=  \y cm]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    \draw ([yshift=1-\y cm] adc\j.east)--++(0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

% version 2
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 16mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
 block/.style = {draw, minimum height=20mm, minimum width=5mm,
                 font=\boldmath,on chain}]
% upper blocks
\node (x1)    [block,draw=none]             {};
\node (ht1)   [block,draw=none]             {\hphantom{$\boldmath(HT)^+$}};
\node (t1)    [block,right=22mm of ht1]     {$T$};
\node (y1)    [block]                       {$Y$};
\node (adc1)  [block]                       {ADC};
% lower blocks
\node (x2)    [block,draw=none,below=of x1] {};
\node (ht2)   [block,draw=none]             {\hphantom{$\boldmath(HT)^+$}};
\node (t2)    [block,right=22mm of ht2]     {$T$};
\node (y2)    [block]                       {$Y$};
\node (adc2)  [block]                       {ADC};
% common input nodes
\node (in1)   [draw,inner sep=0pt, fit= (x1)  (x2), label=center:$\boldmath\hat{x}$] {};
\node (in2)   [draw,inner sep=0pt, fit=(ht1)  (ht2),label=center:$\boldmath(HT)^+$]  {};
% top blocks
    \node (cpu) [above=5mm of in2]     {CPU};
    \node (rf)  [above=5mm of y1]      {RF-chain};
\draw[densely dotted] ([xshift=11mm] cpu.north -| in2.east) coordinate (in3)
                    -- (in3 |- in2.south);
% lines between blocks
    \foreach \y in {-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75}
{
% 8 input lines
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm] x1.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm] x2.west)--++(180:1cm);
}
% 2 lines between other blocks
    \foreach \j in {1, 2}
{
        \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25}
    {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially x\j)] in {ht\j,t\j,y\j,adc\j}
    \draw ([yshift=  \y cm]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    \draw ([yshift=1-\y cm] adc\j.east)--++(0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    }
}
  \end{tikzpicture}

% Version 3
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 20mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
 block/.style = {draw, minimum height=20mm, minimum width=5mm,
                 font=\boldmath,on chain}]
% upper blocks
\node (x1)    [block,draw=none]             {};
\node (ht1)   [block,draw=none]             {\hphantom{$\boldmath(HT)^+$}};
\node (t1)    [block,right=22mm of ht1]     {$T$};
\node (y1)    [block]                       {$Y$};
\node (adc1)  [block]                       {ADC};
% lower blocks
\node (x2)    [block,draw=none,below=of x1] {};
\node (ht2)   [block,draw=none]             {\hphantom{$\boldmath(HT)^+$}};
\node (t2)    [block,right=22mm of ht2]     {$T$};
\node (y2)    [block]                       {$Y$};
\node (adc2)  [block]                       {ADC};
% common input nodes
\node (in1)   [draw,inner sep=0pt, fit= (x1)  (x2), label=center:$\boldmath\hat{x}$] {};
\node (in2)   [draw,inner sep=0pt, fit=(ht1)  (ht2),label=center:$\boldmath(HT)^+$] {};
% top blocks
    \node (cpu) [above=5mm of in2]     {CPU};
    \node (rf)  [above=5mm of y1]      {RF-chain};
\draw[densely dotted] ([xshift=11mm] cpu.north -| in2.east) coordinate (in3)
                    -- (in3 |- in2.south);
% lines between blocks
    \foreach \y in {-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75}
{
% 8 input lines
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm +1 cm] in1.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm -1 cm] in1.west)--++(180:1cm);
% 4 lines between x and HT
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm] in2.west) -- ([yshift=\y cm] in1.east |- in2.west);
}
% 2 lines between other blocks
    \foreach \j in {1, 2}
{
        \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25}
    {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially ht\j)] in {t\j,y\j,adc\j}
    \draw ([yshift=  \y cm]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    \draw ([yshift= 0.5 cm -\y cm] adc\j.east)--++(0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    \draw ([yshift=-0.5 cm -\y cm] adc\j.east)--++([xshift=1.5cm] 0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}    
    \end{document}
```

Now should be easy to make a new version with different numbers of lines and antennas. I hope so.

Comment: Thank you very much! But the number of lines at the input of (TH)^+ should be 4. But I will try to fix it. otherwise you can have a quick look if it is easy to fix. The output of the T boxes should only be two lines each then.

Comment: To clarify even more the right side of the (hT)^+ box should only have 4 lines connected to it. The rest to the left is 8 as usual. But the left side of both T boxes should have only 2 lines in order to match with the right side of the (HT)^+ box

Comment: That is not quite right, I made a modicication in paint that you can see: http://imgur.com/AhCIz41